# inserting tables into an access database using java and showing them into a JtextArea

Tags: java

im new in this so im having some troubles showing and inserting data into access tables, my first trouble is that i cant insert values in my data base , and when i show the data from the tables it shows just the last register but not all of them, im sorry for my english this is not my native language. please help me

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;


public class Formulario { 
    int x,y;
    JButton min,close;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Formulario window = new Formulario();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    public Formulario() {


         frame();

    }

    public void frame(){

     frame = new JFrame();
     frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setUndecorated(true) ;
    frame.setOpacity(0.9f);
    min = new JButton();
    min.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/min.jpg"));
    min.setBorder(null);
    min.setBounds(728, 15, 59, 60);
    min.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //clase interna anonima
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setExtendedState(frame.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR); 
            }

        });
    min.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            min.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/min.jpg"));

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            min.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/min.jpg"));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            min.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/min1.jpg"));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            min.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/min1.jpg"));
        }
     { //clase interna anonima



            }});

    close = new JButton();
    close.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/power.jpg"));
    close.setBorder(null);
    close.setBounds(728, 85, 59, 58);
    close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //clase interna anonima
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);      

            }

        });
 close.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            close.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/Power.jpg"));

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            close.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/Power.jpg"));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            close.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/Power1.jpg"));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            close.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/Power1.jpg"));
        }
     { //clase interna anonima



            }});

    frame.add(min);
    frame.add(close);
    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              x = e.getX(); 
               y = e.getY(); 

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        { //clase interna anonima

           }});

    frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() ; 
            frame.setLocation(point.x - x, point.y - y)   ;             
        }
        });

    JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
    westPanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, Color.YELLOW, new Color(255, 0, 0)));
    westPanel.setBounds(25, 127, 238, 246);
    frame.getContentPane().add(westPanel);
    westPanel.setLayout(null);

    txtemail = new JTextField();
    txtemail.setBounds(90, 99, 86, 20);
    westPanel.add(txtemail);
    txtemail.setColumns(10);

    celular = new JLabel("Celular");
    celular.setBounds(10, 130, 54, 14);
    westPanel.add(celular);

    txtnombre = new JTextField();
    txtnombre.setBounds(90, 33, 86, 20);
    westPanel.add(txtnombre);
    txtnombre.setColumns(10);

    email = new JLabel("Email");
    email.setBounds(10, 99, 54, 14);
    westPanel.add(email);

    txtapellido = new JTextField();
    txtapellido.setBounds(90, 68, 86, 20);
    westPanel.add(txtapellido);
    txtapellido.setColumns(10);

     apellido = new JLabel("Apellido");
    apellido.setBounds(10, 68, 54, 14);
    westPanel.add(apellido);

    txtcelular = new JTextField();
    txtcelular.setBounds(90, 130, 86, 20);
    westPanel.add(txtcelular);
    txtcelular.setColumns(10);

     nombre = new JLabel("Nombre");
    nombre.setBounds(10, 33, 54, 14);
    westPanel.add(nombre);
    conectar = new JButton("Conectar");
    conectar.setBounds(531, 29, 122, 35);
    conectar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //clase interna anonima
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                SimpleDataSource.init();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            url = bdfield.getText();
            try {
                 conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection(url);
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Conexion Exitosa");
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   


        }});


     ingresar = new JButton("Ingresar");
    ingresar.setBounds(62, 180, 82, 23);
    ingresar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //clase interna anonima
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            try {


                //stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Andres','Garcia')");

                stat = conn.createStatement();
                // stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES("+txtnombre.getText()+" ,'"+txtapellido.getText()+"',"+txtemail.getText()+"',"+txtcelular.getText()+")");
                 stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Andres','Garcia')");
                 //stat.executeUpdate(dat);

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }});
    westPanel.add(ingresar);

    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
    northPanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW));
    northPanel.setBounds(25, 27, 685, 89);
    frame.getContentPane().add(northPanel);
    northPanel.setLayout(null);

     bd = new JLabel("URL Base de Datos");
    bd.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    bd.setBounds(10, 29, 170, 35);
    northPanel.add(bd);

    bdfield = new JTextField();
    bdfield.setBounds(145, 31, 376, 35);
    northPanel.add(bdfield);
    bdfield.setColumns(10);

    northPanel.add(conectar);


     info = new JTextArea();
    info.setEditable(false);
    info.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    info.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    info.setBounds(318, 163, 392, 210);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(info);
    frame.getContentPane().add(info);


    listar = new JButton("Listar");
    listar.setBounds(317, 127, 89, 23);
    listar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //clase interna anonima
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Test");
                while(result.next()){


                info.setText(result.getString("Nombre")+" "+result.getString("Apellido")+" "+result.getString("Email")+" "+result.getString("Celular"));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }finally
              {

                    //conn.close();
                // catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    //e1.printStackTrace();

              }
            //info.setText(SimpleDataSource.getConnection());

        }});

    frame.getContentPane().add(listar);


}
    public  JTextField bdfield;
    private JButton conectar;
    private JButton ingresar;
    private JLabel bd;
    private JLabel nombre;
    private JLabel apellido;
    private JLabel email;
    private JLabel celular;
    private JTextField txtnombre;
    private JTextField txtapellido;
    private JTextField txtemail;
    private JTextField txtcelular;
    private JButton listar;
    private JTextArea info;
    private JFrame frame;
    public Connection conn;
public String url; 
public Statement stat;
public ResultSet result;
}
```

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;


/**
   A simple data source for getting database connections. 
*/
public class SimpleDataSource
{

   /**
      Initializes the data source.
      @param fileName the name of the property file that 
      contains the database driver, URL, username, and password
   */
   public static void init()
         throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
   {  


      String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
      //url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//Erick//Documents//tester.mdb";
      username = "";
      password = "ecuador";

      //Class.forName(driver);
   }

   /**
      Gets a connection to the database.
      @return the database connection
   */
   public static Connection getConnection(String url) throws SQLException
   {
      return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+url, username, password);
   }

   private static String url;
   private static String username;
   private static String password;
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: why i cant see all the registers and why i cant insert data into the table test t says something about "row column count mismatch"

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Don't use `MouseListener` with buttons, in you case, you could probably get the functionality from the inbuilt roll over support and changing the state when the `ActionListener` is triggered

Comment: Have you tried committing the results or is auto commit enabled?

Comment: thanks for your advices, and yes is auto commit enabled

Answer (score 0):

## Insert issues...

- Have you tried calling [`Connection#commit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit())?
- Have you tried setting [`Connection#autoCommit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)) to `true`?

As a general preferences, `PreparedStatement`s are preferred.  See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details...

## Presentation issues...

What, exactly do you think `JTextArea#setText` does?

Perhaps, instead, you should try [`JTextArea#append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String))

FYI: `new ImageIcon("src/...")` will come back to haunt you.  Instead, you should be using `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/...")))`